# How can I use a Lift onSubmit value in a second snippet class?

Tags: scala, lift

how can I use a value in a second snippet?

For example I've got the age in an form:

```
  <div>
    <form class="lift:OnSubmit?form=post">
      Age: <input name="age" value="0"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Snippet:

```
object OnSubmit {
  def render = {

    var age = 0
​
    // process the form
    def process() {
        S.notice("Age: "+age)
        S.redirectTo("/")
      }
    }

    "name=age" #> SHtml.onSubmit(s => asInt(s).foreach(age = _)) &
    "type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(process)
  }
}
```

How can I use the value from the age in another snippet class?

Thank you!

Best regards,
John

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind one input element once, so you'd have to either make a note of the value in a RequestVar, and use that in the other class, or possibly, if its just the same logic and not the exact same element break the functionality out into a trait and just mix that into the other snippet class.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do though?